# Merging a list of tuples with a list into a list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have two lists, as follows:

```
list_1 = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
list_2 = [7, 8, 9]
```

How can I combine the two into a single list

```
list_3 = [(1, 2, 7), (3, 4, 8), (5, 6, 9)]
```

using only one comprehension?

I'm sure someone has already asked this, but I probably was not able to phrase my question well enough to find that post.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#zip) :

```
In [17]: [i+(j,) for i, j in zip(list_1, list_2)]
Out[17]: [(1, 2, 7), (3, 4, 8), (5, 6, 9)]
```